# How to fix slow Remote Desktop To Windows 7 PC?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, macbook-pro

I'm using Remote Desktop for Mac on my base Retina MBP.

Remote Desktop is incredibly slow for connecting to my Windows 7 PC.

Why is to so slow?
Are there other alternatives that will work faster?

Comment: What is your OS? Do you use the Microsoft Remote Desktop application, Cord, or another application? Which version of the application are you using? How do you connect? By IP address or by hostname? Do you connect to the default 3389 port or another port? What is slow, for example the time to connect or screen updates? Where is your Windows 7 PC located, remote, in a DMZ, in the same local LAN?

Comment: I'm using Mountain Lion on a freshly installed partition. I'm using Microsoft Remote Desktop version 2.1.1. I tried to connect both my Vista machine and my Win 7 Machine. I'm connecting by IP address, because for some reason it can't find the hostnames(both Vista & Win7), default port, and I don't have DMZ. The screen updates slowly, don't mind the time it takes to connect the machine.

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/319693/why-are-remote-desktop-clients-rdp-very-slow-on-my-mac/857413#857413

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to know why it may be slow without having access to more detailed info about your current setup.  However if you want to try alternatives to check whether it's consistently slow (and therefore perhaps infrastructure based) or just the MS app that's slow, then you can do worse than try to use *[CORD](http://cord.sourceforge.net)* which is a nice open source remote desktop alternative that's free.

Comment: Just tried CORD and it works much faster than Remote Desktop, which is really good and cool. Is it possible to work full-screen with it?

Comment: Also, should I  try Real VNC ?

Comment: See other options here: http://superuser.com/a/857413/39364

Answer (score 1):

You can fix slow remote desktop to windows 7 PC as follows:

- Launch Remote Desktop and put in the remote computer you want to connect to.
- Hit the Options button.
- When the Options menu opens up, reduce the Remote desktop size and choose a lower color setting. Also under the Experience tab I uncheck everything except Reconnect if connection is dropped.
- Hit Connect.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try Ericom Blaze, which is an RDP acceleration and compression solution.  Blaze can accelerate the RDP connection by up to 10 times normal RDP.

Get more info [here](http://www.ericom.com/ericom_blaze.asp?URL_ID=708)

Please note that I work for Ericom.